# toString() works differently between Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, svg

I've a little (big) problem with the function .toString().
I've a string that contains an SVG polyline and I need to get "points" attribute.
I've tried with myPoly.toString() but in all cases I receive different answer if I run my app in Firefox or IE.
In firefox I receive the value correctly as It is written into SVG, in IE the points strings are transformed in numbers.

*Example:*

**Firefox**

polyline id="1191" points="303270.685842807,4628092.26231488 303132.683184,4628154.95824449 303058.00286968,4628191.46425108 303006.318032042,4628217.33599697 302959.834485566,4628250.84303829 302913.412651264,4628286.5711075 302804.378175552,4628374.03209193 302771.994016706,4628406.03998642 302741.241605215,4628436.89177469

**IE**

polyline id="1191" points="303271,4.62809e+006 303133,4.62816e+006 303058,4.62819e+006 303006,4.62822e+006 302960,4.62825e+006 302913,4.62829e+006 302804,4.62837e+006 302772,4.62841e+006 302741,4.62844e+006

How can I prevent the transformation?

Thanks. Alessandra.

Comment: IE is rounding, and `e` is just exponential. I'm not sure you can prevent this, that's just the way IE stringifies the path, but they're the same number, floats aren't so precise.

Comment: Are you sure that a) the two browsers use the same version of the code and not a cached one b) the "conversion" is not only a feature of whatever console you use to display the string?

Comment: Two outputs are really different. So my application doesn't work correctly in IE. I have to compare points and two equal points in firefox are different for IE :(

Comment: Why is it problematic that the output is different? The exponential notation is valid. You can get back the numeric value by using parseFloat(), e.g. console.log(parseFloat("4.62809e+006"));

Comment: Furthermore if you look this 303270.685842807,4628092.26231488 303271,4.62809e+006 you can see that the X coord is rounded, so I lost decimal part.

Comment: This is not a rounding problem, the number is off by too much. Is it possible that IE just renders the shape a bit different?

Comment: Wolfang i think you're right. I tried to copy the polyline string in a simple string var, print toString() result and it's ok.

Comment: Since SnapSvg uses Jquery It could be a Jquery problem? i can't explain me the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The string value of an svg polygon(and paths) is returned differently betweeen browsers based on the location spaces and commas. Parsing via indexOf will not work cross=browser.
Polygon points are consitent cross-browser when we use the point list. Then when comparing x,y values, you can round to the 'safe' decimal places for your app...I've used 4.

```
var polyPoints=myPolygon.points
var n=polyPoints.numberOfItems
for(var k=0;k<n;k++)
{
  var xy=polyPoints.getItem(k)
  var x=xy.x
  var y=xy.y
// ...
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much Francis!!!! I'll try your code tomorrow morning. 
If it works i will check you answer as correct and send you a box of sicilian arancinis!!! :)